# An interesting relation of integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

Proof that there does not exist an $F: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx =F(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx, \int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx).$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First consider $f(x)=g(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}$. Then consider $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{2})$.

**Hint2:** Consider $f(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}+a$ and $g(x) =x-\frac{1}{2}+b$. Then $f(x)=a$ and $g(x) = b$.

Comment: Can you detail , please?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$, $f=2a$ for $x<1/2$, 0 elsewhere, $g=2b$ on $(1/2,1)$, 0 elsewhere. We get $F(a,b)=0$. Obviously a contradiction.

Comment: F($\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$, $\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx$) is a combination of these integrals at any power.

Comment: Thanks! But why F(a,b)=0 is a contradiction?

Comment: You get a contradiction by taking $f(x)=g(x)=1$ for all $x$.